# Recycleview on scroll throws java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException on last item position

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, admob

I have an array List which contains 15 items in it and I am using admob native ads in recycleview in my app and i have got two problems that i cant quite figure out how to deal with.
The first problem is that i want to show first ads after lets say 7th item , but the first ad is shown at the 0th position .
And the second problem is when i reach the end of the list i get `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:` . Can anyone here please help me in figuring out what am i doing wrong here any help would be really appreciated .
Here is my code:

```
class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
private static final int TYPE_AD= 0;
private static final int TYPE_NORMAL= 1;
public static final int ITEMS_PER_AD = 7;
Context context;
List<UnifiedNativeAd> mNativeAds = new ArrayList<>();
List<Quote> mQuotes;

private static final int NUMBER_OF_ADS = 5;
private AdLoader adLoader;
private String ADMOB_NATIVE_AD_UNIIT = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110";

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<Quote> quotes) {
    this.context = context;
    this.mQuotes = quotes;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    if(viewType == TYPE_AD)
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(this.context).inflate(R.layout.ad_unified,parent,false);
        return new UnifiedNativeAdViewHolder(view);
    }
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(this.context).inflate(R.layout.quotes_list_item,parent,false);
    return new QuoteViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
{
    int viewType = getItemViewType(position);

    switch (viewType) {
        case TYPE_NORMAL :
            QuoteViewHolder vh = (QuoteViewHolder) holder;

            Quote current = (Quote) mQuotes.get(position);
            vh.txtName.setText(current.getQuote());
            vh.txtEmail.setText(current.getCategoryId());
            break;
        case TYPE_AD:
            //fall through
        default:
            UnifiedNativeAdViewHolder adViewHolder = (UnifiedNativeAdViewHolder) holder;
            AdLoader.Builder builder = new AdLoader.Builder(context, ADMOB_NATIVE_AD_UNIIT);
            adLoader = builder.forUnifiedNativeAd(unifiedNativeAd -> {
                mNativeAds.add(unifiedNativeAd);
                if (!adLoader.isLoading()) {
                    UnifiedNativeAd nativeAd = (UnifiedNativeAd) mNativeAds.get(position);
                    populateNativeAdView( nativeAd, (adViewHolder.getAdView()));
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }).withAdListener(new AdListener(){
                @Override
                public void onAdFailedToLoad(LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                    super.onAdFailedToLoad(loadAdError);
                }
            })
                    .build();
            adLoader.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (mNativeAds != null) return mQuotes.size() + mNativeAds.size();
    else return mQuotes.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position)
{
    return (position % ITEMS_PER_AD == 0) ? TYPE_AD: TYPE_NORMAL;
}
```

and here is my logcat

```
2020-11-22 19:50:51.372 589-589/com.example.test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.test, PID: 589
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 14, Size: 3
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
    at com.example.test.RecyclerViewAdapter.lambda$onBindViewHolder$0$RecyclerViewAdapter(RecyclerViewAdapter.java:79)
    at com.example.test.-$$Lambda$RecyclerViewAdapter$rjtX5KhLYVLI7Av-VFSBy8gWizI.onUnifiedNativeAdLoaded(Unknown Source:6)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzagx.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.5.0:6)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzagb.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.5.0:18)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzgw.onTransact(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-base@@19.5.0:13)
    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:630)
    at ge.b(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@204102000@204102000000.334548305.334548305:2)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.formats.client.au.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@204102000@204102000000.334548305.334548305:0)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.ad.nativead.ad.run(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:794)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at qj.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@204102000@204102000000.334548305.334548305:0)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.f.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@204102000@204102000000.334548305.334548305:1)
    at qj.dispatchMessage(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@204102000@204102000000.334548305.334548305:0)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
```

this is where i am getting error

```
UnifiedNativeAd nativeAd = (UnifiedNativeAd) mNativeAds.get(position);
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue because the size mNativeAds smaller than the size of the summation of two lists, when you scroll up you call the index such as 15, of course not found on mNativeAds list with size 7 .

Rather than use the old position of mNativeAds list :

```
UnifiedNativeAd nativeAd = (UnifiedNativeAd) mNativeAds.get(position);
```

use the new position based on the summation

```
UnifiedNativeAd nativeAd = (UnifiedNativeAd) mNativeAds.get(newPosition);
```

Answer (score 0):

in getItemCount you are returning the sum of the size of mQuotes and mNativeAds, which is larger than mNativeAds size. So mNativeAds throws some exception on higher position.

You should use a single list for both ( mQuotes and mNativeAds) and adapt your logic accordingly.

'''

```
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

//Reason of your problem.

        if (mNativeAds != null) return mQuotes.size() + mNativeAds.size();
        else return mQuotes.size();
    }
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

Try the following 3 code changes:

1. `Quote current = (Quote) mQuotes.get(position);` change to `Quote current = (Quote) mQuotes.get(position - position / ITEMS_PER_AD);`
2. `UnifiedNativeAd nativeAd = (UnifiedNativeAd) mNativeAds.get(position);` change to  `UnifiedNativeAd nativeAd = (UnifiedNativeAd) mNativeAds.get((position / ITEMS_PER_AD - 1) / mNativeAds.size());`
3. `return (position % ITEMS_PER_AD == 0) ? TYPE_AD: TYPE_NORMAL;` change to `return (position != 0 && (position % ITEMS_PER_AD == 0)) ? TYPE_AD : TYPE_NORMAL;`